# Execute exe-file with bat-file from Python

Tags: python, batch-file

I have an exe-file that I need to run several times with different parameters. I can manually (or with Python) create a bat-file with all the parameters and then run the exe-file

C:\RAY\Reflec.exe < test.bat

in a cmd window but I run into problems when I try to make Python run it. The exe-file is executed but it does not take in the parameters in the bat-file. I have tried various ways, *e.g.* using os.startfile, subprocess.call, and so on but I can not get it to work. All I achieve is to run the exe-file but then it is waiting for the parameters. I don't get any error messages.

Can someone please help me with the syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.system("D:/Ramesh/test.bat")
```

Comment: your test.bat should contain the exe file path.

Comment: Thanks, but the result is the same. I added the exe-file on the first line in the bat-file. It starts ok but it does not take the parameters on the following lines. This is how the bat-file looks like:

Reflec.exe\n
\n
1\n
2\n
...

Comment: open your bat file with Notepad and add like   "C:\RAY\Reflec.exe"   save and close

Comment: Sorry, but this did not work either. I need to figure out how to execute Reflec.exe from Python and have it use the parameters in test.bat as input. My Python script is generating the test.bat file. It works just fine when I manually run C:\RAY\Reflec.exe < Test.bat from the command prompt, but I can't figure out how to make Python do it. Python starts Reflec.exe but nothing happens, it is just waiting for the input that was supposed to come from Test.bat... :-(